# Is it possible to attach a URL to a Twilio Image in an MMS?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We're sending a URL to our website in a text message to users through a Twilio custom function, but the URL is long and unsightly. Is it possible to send an image to a user that they can then tap and be redirected to our website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid to say that it is not possible to attach a URL to a Twilio Image in an MMS. I'd recommend shortening the URL with [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) or [goo.gl](https://goo.gl).

Comment: It's been several years since this was answered. Is this still not possible? Is this due to functionalities within MMS itself? Any potential workarounds to achieve the same behavior. Thanks!